# Dynamic Number Of Inputs In Form

Tags: forms, ms-access

This is supposed to be something very common in access: Say you have a table `Employees` with a many-to-many relationship with a table `Workdays`. As in, A day of work is a record in `Workdays`, and for any day of work there can be multiple employees who worked that day (Which is shown with a third table, I think it's called a junction table?).

Now, say you want to create a form that the user inputs the employees who worked on a certain day. There is a changing number of employees per day, therefore a changing number of text boxes/combo boxes to input the employees in.

I want to ask if there's a conventional/convenient/acceptable way to do this. I've thought of 2 ways: Having a certain maximum number of text boxes invisible, and every time one receives input set the visible property on a new one to `Visible=True`, and second way by using the `CreateControl` method. Both ways seem a little pointlessly complicated for something that should be very common.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to mess with dynamically creating or showing/hiding individual controls. All you probably need is a main form for the Workday with a Subform Control for the Employees who worked that day, something like this:

Design View:

[image: DesignView.png]

Form View:

[image: FormView.png]

The subform control contains a Continuous Forms form that is bound to the junction table [TimeCards].

```
Workday    EmployeeID  HoursWorked
---------  ----------  ----------- 
9/10/2014           1            7
9/10/2014           3            6
9/10/2014           4            9
```

The "child" subform linked to the "master" form by the [Workday] value. You can enter a variable number of entries for a given Workday by simply adding new rows to the subform (via the "New Record" row with the asterisk beside it).

For more information, see

[Create a form that contains a subform](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-HA101872705.aspx)